# Laravel count Support Tickets from a user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this in the Dashboard [Screenshot of the Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJXAK.png)

I want that it shows how many Tickets are open / closed / all

How do I do this with this Database?[Screenshot from SELECT * FROM `tickets`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7as.png)

How do I do this that every user see his own open / closed and all tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your blade.php file you could do:

```
{{ $tickets->where('status', 'Open')->count() }}
```

To use this you need to pass $tickets from your controller to your view. Here's an example of what that might look:

```
public function DashboardController(){
   $tickets = Ticket::get();
   return view('yourviewname', compact('tickets');
}
```

What's great about this solution is that you can display it the way you want using only 1 query:

```
{{ $tickets->where('status', 'Closed')->count() }}
{{ $tickets->count() }}
```

Join some code next time :-)

### Update

If you are not passing any data to your view you can also use (where Ticket is your model name)

```
{{ Ticket::where('status', 'Open')->get()->count() }}
```

Comment: And what do I have to put in the Controller?

Comment: @Tim. I just updated the response. If you want to use the first version, you should load the Tickets inside the controller like "$tickets = Tickets::get();" and then add them when you return the view like "return view('myview', compact('tickets');"